# Odoo 16 How to add an item to this drop-down box

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Odoo 16 How to add an item to this drop-down box?

[image]

Trying to look here
odoo\addons\portal\views\portal_templates.xml
But I don't get it. Trying to add a menu item there, e.g. with a redirect to the page.
Thanks in advance, even if you just give me a hint, I'm still just learning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it the right way, here's the solution, maybe it will be useful to someone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="my_itemmenu" name="my_itemmenu" inherit_id="portal.user_dropdown">
        <xpath expr="//*[@id='o_logout_divider']" position="before">
            <a href="/my/add-child" role="menuitem" class="dropdown-item ps-3">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-child me-1 small text-muted"/>my_itemmenu
            </a>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).